# Summarising data into year ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to sumarise data in sql and am having difficulty finding a method for grouping data.

i have a table named cars

```
CarID CarMake  CarModel CarYear
1      Ford      Mondeo   2000
2      Ford      Mondeo   2002
3      Ford      Mondeo   2003
4      Ford      Mondeo   2005
```

I want to be able to group this data to appear as

```
CarMake CarModel CarYearRange
Ford     Mondeo   2000-2003
Ford     Mondeo   2005-2005
```

I Have tried using min and max to produce this however this fails if the car wasn't made in a year between as in the example.

Comment: How do you decide the year ranges?

Answer (score 2):

```
select carmake, carmodel, 
case  when caryear >= 2000 and caryear <=2003 then '2000-2003' 
     when caryear >= 2005 and caryear <=2005 then '2005-2005'
end  t
from car
group by carmake, carmodel , t
```

for [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/6db05/2)

Comment: Can you check that this works in SQL-SERVER, per the question tag?

Answer (score 2):

I have assumed (perhaps brashly) that your sample data contains an error, and that the ranges should be 2000, 2002-2003, and 2005 since there is no model for 2001 or 2004. If I'm right then this will work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Cars.CarMake, 
            Cars.CarModel, 
            [FirstYear] = Cars.CarYear, 
            [LastYear] = Cars.CarYear, 
            [Recursion] = 1
    FROM    Cars
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  CTE.CarMake, 
            CTE.CarModel, 
            CTE.[FirstYear], 
            [LastYear] = Cars.CarYear, 
            [Recursion] = [Recursion] + 1
    FROM    CTE 
            INNER JOIN Cars
                ON CTE.CarMake = Cars.CarMake
                AND CTE.CarModel = Cars.CarModel
                AND CTE.[LastYear] = Cars.CarYear - 1
), MaxCTE AS
(   SELECT  CarMake, 
            CarModel, 
            FirstYear, 
            LastYear, 
            Recursion, 
            [MaxRecursion] = MAX(Recursion) OVER(PARTITION BY CarMake, CarModel, FirstYear)
    FROM    CTE
)
SELECT  MaxCTE.CarMake, 
        MaxCTE.CarModel, 
        [CarYearRange] = CAST(FirstYear AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' - ' + CAST(LastYear AS VARCHAR(4))
FROM    MaxCTE
WHERE   Recursion = MaxRecursion
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    MaxCTE ex
            WHERE   MaxCTE.CarMake = ex.CarMake
            AND     MaxCTE.CarModel = ex.CarModel
            AND     MaxCTE.FirstYear > ex.FirstYear
            AND     MaxCTE.LastYear = ex.LastYear
        )
```

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22a3b/1)**

**EDIT**

**USE RICHARD THE KIWI'S ANSWER IF I HAVE INTERPRETED THE REQUIREMENTS CORRECTLY. IT IS MUCH BETTER THAN MINE!**

**[Fiddle for the improved solution](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22a3b/3)**

```
SELECT  CarMake,
        CarModel,
        [StartYear] = MIN(CarYear),
        [EndYear] = MAX(CarYear)
FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                    [Offset] = CarYear - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarMake, CarModel ORDER BY CarYear)
            FROM    Cars
        ) x
GROUP BY CarMake, CarModel, Offset
ORDER BY CarMake, CarModel, StartYear
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use something similar to this:

```
select distinct carmake, 
  carmodel,
  case 
    when caryear >= 2000 and caryear <= 2003 then '2000-2003'
    when caryear >= 2005 and caryear <= 2005 then '2005-2005'
  end CarYearRange
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9633c/2)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a cue from GarethD's interpretation of your requirements, here's my query to get the result desired.  I would strongly advise showing the range as 2 distinct columns, and letting the front-end code merge them for display if required.

```
select carmake,
       carmodel,
       min(caryear) startyear,
       max(caryear) endyear
from (
  select *,
         offset= caryear-row_number() over (partition by carmake, carmodel
                                            order by caryear)
  from cars
) x
group by carmake, carmodel, offset
order by carmake, carmodel, startyear
```

Comment: +1 Much better than my solution. A trick I have seen many times and forgotten just as many times. Hopefully this time it will lodge in my memory!